# Symfony 4 FOSUserBundle Error too many redirect

Tags: php, symfony, redirect, authentication, fosuserbundle

I'm using FriendsOfSymfony UserBundle in Symfony 4 and PHP 7.2. I've already finished my project and want to deploy it. So I
1. Change php version in the server
2. Change in .env file dev to log
3. Just upload all my files to server (without dev cache, its too big)

After opened the window I can see many redirection in developmanager in Google Chrome. Always to /login. Ok, I've tried change the security.yml and other strange things what I found in the internet. Nothin works. I've tried to delete checking access in some routes and just test if it'll work, but also not.

My full security.yml
    security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
        logout: true
        anonymous: true

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/profile, role: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/profile/edit, role: ROLE_USER }

access_denied_url: /
```

Anyone has this problem too?

Answer (score 0):

I'd think your problem is related to your libraries.
Try `composer install` or `composer install --optimize-autoloader` and make sure the bootstrap file exists in `var`, and that `var/` is writable by the web server user. Finally clear your cache `bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`

Comment: Ok, but let me understand. I dont know how to correctly deploy my app. I just change the environment and upload the files by FTPClient to serwer. For example my Bootstrap is added by CDN. I dont have it in var. Is it wrong? And in var I only have log and cache because its symfony 4. In my localhost everything works correctly but this problem is only in the other server. Ok, i just locally done "composer install", "composer install --optimize-autoloader" and "bin/console cache:clear --env=dev" and "bin/console cache:clear --env=prod". Then I uploaded all files again. Problem still exist :(

Comment: I have made very bad experiences with web hostings where you can only upload the files because you don't have shell access. Be very careful about permissions and hidden files!

Answer (score 0):

I believe what causes this problem are routes that end with a slash: `/`, also called a 'trailing slash'. There are three solutions to this problem:

1. Make sure none of your routes end with a trailing slash. This means you will also have to override some of the default routes of the FOSUser bundle, because there are some that end in `/`.
2. Redirect all routes with a trailing slash. There is [documentation on how to do this](http://symfony.com/doc/4.0/routing/redirect_trailing_slash.html) on the symfony website.
3. Upgrade to symfony 4.1, where routes with a trailing slash are automatically redirected.

Comment: I have: Symfony 4.1.1 (kernel: src, env: prod, debug: false)
And all my routes (except "/" home page) don't end with  a slash "/".
I bet it's small error somewhere but after all other errors FOS isnt for me...

Comment: Maybe its because wrong server configuration? I just change basic path to /public.
I show that redirections are /login to / to /login to /

Comment: I change home page route and now I know its login redirect me to "/" , next it redirect to login back because I'm not logged user. But why login redirect to "/" ?

Comment: Even if I change permissions and make one route public without authentication its stil redirect to login page.

Comment: See what happens when you remove/uncomment the line `access_denied_url: /`

Comment: unfortunately the same :(